# The mysqli_connect not working

Tags: php, mysql

I installed apache, php and mysql. Now when I execute the php code, the `mysqli_connect()` is not working, neither it's showing the message in die.

```
$dbc=mysqli_connect(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ') or die('not connecting');
```

Now someone tell me what database username shall I pass to `mysqli_connect` and what password. I don't remember I was asked for any username or password 
and why isn't the message in `die()` showing up?

My `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));` outputs bool(false).. if it has anything to do with it, how do I correct it.?

Comment: Try `"root"` as username and either `null` as password, or something that you entered (you wrote in comments that you entered some password).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like MySQLi extension is not installed. What does `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));` output?

Comment: Then you're actually getting fatal error when calling `mysqli_connect()`, because that function does not exist. If it is Windows server, locate `php.ini` file and uncomment `extension=php_mysqli.dll` line, then restart Apache. This should enable MySQLi extension. See more about enabling/installing mysqli @ http://lv.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: @binaryLV  i tried it, removed the ; in front of the extensio=php_mysqli.dll  but still it is showing bool(false)

Comment: If using PHP 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, then it is written in documentation that `libmysql.dll` file (included in PHP distribution) must be available in the Windows system's PATH environment variable. Copying that file to the directory where apache is installed also might work (in that case, there's no need to modify PATH environment variable).

Comment: @binaryLV I love you. saved hours

Comment: Oh man..... been at this for an hour. thanks for not making it into days of waste!

Comment: mysqli_connect does not work in my cpanel. what sholud i do?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` And `ini_set('display_errors',1);` ?

The problem could be somewhere else.

Also how do you know it's failing if it is not priting the message in `Die()`?

Comment: will check. what would be my username for database?

Comment: @Karan: I am not a magician. :). Anyway the default is root with no password

Comment: i mean, while installing mysql, i wasnt asked for anyusername, but i did enter the password, so how do i know what username to pass in mysqli_connect function?

Comment: Don't connect as root! Create a new username with privileges only to one database. If you use the root user to connect to the database, any flaw exploited in your application may grant an attacker root access to the database, which means ALL your databases will be exposed. If you use a new user who only has access to one database, only that database will be exposed (yeah, it also sucks, but on a inmensely minor scale)

Answer (score 3):

for the host, if you are using "localhost:8889",
try using "localhost", and in the mysqli_connect() put in '8889' (or whatever port you are using) as an argument after the other arguements.

worked for me.

eg:

```
mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','dbname','8889');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass no values, I think MySQL is [using defaults](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) from the settings ini. So maybe this happens too if you pass empty values.  In that case the connection could actually be established, and the result won't 'die'. Best thing is to use `var_dump` to check what `$dbc` contains after the call and continue from there.

But anyway, there is no way, PHP is going to tell you which settings to use if you don't remember them. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed mysql, then there exists only the `root` user, without a password (or blank one if you prefer). You are strongly encouraged to change that password **AND** create a new user and password for your application, who has only access to just one database, the one your application uses.

To change the `root` password, you may do this:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: [press enter]
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET `password`=PASSWORD('your_desired_password') WHERE username='root';

# this next bit is to create a database and a username for your web application
mysql> CREATE DATABASE your_application_name;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON your_application_name.* TO 'your_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

Obviously change all `your_*` values with correct ones.

For the reason why the `die()` gets not executed, do what @yes123 and @binaryLV had said (I think both are right, the `mysqli` is not installed, so it throws a `E_FATAL_ERROR` upon calling `mysqli_connect(...)` and as `error_reporting` is disabled (or maybe `display_errors`, or maybe both), you don't see that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
//1 create a data base connection
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con) {
    die('mysqli connection failed: ' . mysql_error() );
}
//2 connect with a data base 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($con , DB_NAME);  
if (!$db_select) {
    die('data base selection failed: ' . mysql_error() );
}
//3 create query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from subjects");
    if (!$result) {
        die('query not successed: ' . mysql_error() );
    }
//4 use the returned data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['menu_name'] . " " . $row['position'] . "<br>" ;
}
//5 close connection...
if (isset($con)) {      
    mysqli_close($con);
}

Run this code if you have any query then feel free to ask me.
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your php version
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();exit;
if it is above 5.5 and even not working 
then write script in your php file phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);exit;
it show all about php and check Mysqli listed or not. if not then inform to our server admministrator or if you have access then go to phpini file and enable mysqli (remove semicolon from it)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$dbc = @ mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or exit('Not connecting.');
```

Comment: (1) **Never** use (or advise to use) `@`! It's the worst thing for debugging. (2) `mysql_*` is not compatible with `mysqli_*`.