# mysqli_connect() showing error

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

i have written a code in php and i have apache and mysql installed and configured perfectly

```
<?php
echo "entering db php code";
$link=mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','MyRootPassword');
echo "mysqli_connect is called";
if (!$link)
{
    echo "cannection is failed";
    exit();    
}
echo "connection is ok";
?>
```

it's causing an erro. which is ::

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: 
Headers and client library minor      version mismatch. Headers:50051 
Library:50168 in C:\Program Files\Apache Software
Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\db.inc.php on line 3
```

please tell what does this warning mean. and what is wrong with me ?????

Comment: Not that it matters but never use the root user

Comment: can u tell me...after selecting database can i insert values to particular table with help of this code... @s.lenders

Comment: this code only connects. But you can insert and select data after connection with the right user. Preferabel not root but a single user that has the permission on that database. Your error reads "version mismatch" the libary you use has a different version then your server. It can't communicate because of that.

Comment: @s.lenders..how to overcome this error???please help

Comment: @s.lenders...now if i write other codes for insertion with this connection..will it be able to insert???

Comment: You are able to insert with a root connection ofcourse. Though it is not suggested.

Comment: what is the php version you are running?

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the warning by adding '@' before calling the mysqli_connect, like

```
$link = @mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','MyRootPassword');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212920/1765877), your MySQLi extension is most likely not properly installed.

Comment: no my mysqli_extension is properly installed..it must be something else

Comment: maybe you could try deleting that space between `mysqli_connect` and `('localhost','root','MyRootPassword');`

Comment: Can you post the version of both mysql server as the mysqli libary?

Comment: no my mysqli_extension is properly installed and all other sites in this sever works without any problem.